# WebSockets Message Frame Length should be 5, but am getting 33

Tags: websocket, protocols

So I'm trying to decode a websocket message frame at the moment, one such example,

0x81 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58 (contains "Hello")

```
   0                   1                   2                   3
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
  +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
  |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
  |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
  |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
  | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
  +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
  |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
  + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
  |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
  +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
  | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
  +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
  :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
  + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
  |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the payload bits are coming out as 0100001 = 33.  It should be 5 surely?  Or Have I missed something here?

Edit: The value of the header bits to the end of "Payload len" are,

```
1000000110100001
[1][0][0][0][0001][1][0100001]
```

Nick.

Comment: I should point out that in my decoding routine, I'm hardcoding the length to 5 and the message is unmasked successfully, but obviously as it's only an 11 byte message, the payload couldn't possibly be 33 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm being stupid, it's in **bits**, not **bytes**!